# Nested $.when .then()s

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On page load, 12 items with `data-id` attributes are pushed into an array `showcaseIds`:

```
function pushShowcaseIds () {

  showcaseIds = [];

  $("[data-id]").each(function () {
    showcaseIds.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
  });

}

pushShowcaseIds(); // run on load
```

If the user has gone through all of the items in the array (all 12 items), such that the `currentItemId` is null, I want to load more items, wait for the ajax call to finish, push all the new IDs on the page into the array once it's done, then allow the user to continue.

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {

  index = showcaseIds.indexOf(currentItemId);
  cacheCurrent = currentItemId;

  if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39){
      if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        currentItemId = showcaseIds[index + 1];
        if (currentItemId == null){
          $.when(
            loadMore()
          ).then(function(){
            index = showcaseIds.indexOf(cacheCurrent);
            currentItemId = showcaseIds[index + 1]; // undefined
          });
        } else {
          // continue as normal
        }
      }
  }
});

function loadMore () {
  $.when(
    $.ajax({
        // 
    })
  ).then(function(){
    pushShowcaseIds();
  });
}
```

However after the `loadMore()` function is called the `currentItemId` in the $.when.then is undefined and when I `alert` it, it comes up instantly.

So I guess the `then()` appears to be running instantly rather than waiting for the ajax call to finish. I assume this has something to do with the "nested" $.when then()s, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try returning the expression in `loadMore`: `return $.when ...`

Comment: That did it! Thank you, you should post the answer

Comment: Great :) answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot to return the expression inside `loadMore`:

```
function loadMore () {
  return $.when(
    $.ajax({
        // 
    })
  ).then(function(){
    pushShowcaseIds();
  });
}
```